# com.ibm.ws.container.service.metadata.MetaDataException: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, nullpointerexception, websphere-liberty

I just switched a *Pentaho* business server project from MyEclipse Blue to Eclipse Luna. When I star up the liberty profile server 8.5, it ends up in:

```
com.ibm.ws.container.service.metadata.MetaDataException:
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I have no clue what's happening here.
Here's the log:

```
------Start of DE processing------ = [01.07.16 06:18:41:926 MESZ]
Exception = java.lang.NullPointerException
Source = com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer
probeid = createModuleMetaData
Stack Dump = java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.ws.javaee.ddmodel.commonbnd.ResourceRefType.getName(ResourceRefType.java:59)
    at com.ibm.ws.container.service.config.RefBndAndExtHelper.configureResourceRefBindings(RefBndAndExtHelper.java:61)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.container.config.WebAppConfiguratorHelper.configureResourceRefBindings(WebAppConfiguratorHelper.java:1858)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.container.config.WebAppConfiguratorHelper.configureWebBnd(WebAppConfiguratorHelper.java:674)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.container.config.WebAppConfigurator.configure(WebAppConfigurator.java:241)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.container.config.WebAppConfigurationAdapter.adapt(WebAppConfigurationAdapter.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.container.config.WebAppConfigurationAdapter.adapt(WebAppConfigurationAdapter.java:43)
    at com.ibm.ws.adaptable.module.internal.AdapterFactoryServiceImpl.adapt(AdapterFactoryServiceImpl.java:189)
    at com.ibm.ws.adaptable.module.internal.AdaptableContainerImpl.adapt(AdaptableContainerImpl.java:171)
    at com.ibm.ws.adaptable.module.internal.InterpretedContainerImpl.adapt(InterpretedContainerImpl.java:204)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.createModuleMetaData(WebContainer.java:619)
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.web.internal.WebModuleHandlerImpl.deployModule(WebModuleHandlerImpl.java:112)
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.DeployedAppInfoBase.deployModule(DeployedAppInfoBase.java:533)
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.DeployedAppInfoBase.deployModules(DeployedAppInfoBase.java:479)
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.DeployedAppInfoBase.deployApp(DeployedAppInfoBase.java:406)
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.ear.internal.EARApplicationHandlerImpl.install(EARApplicationHandlerImpl.java:75)
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.StartAction.execute(StartAction.java:134)
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.ApplicationStateMachineImpl.enterState(ApplicationStateMachineImpl.java:1277)
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.ApplicationStateMachineImpl.run(ApplicationStateMachineImpl.java:876)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

The contents of ibm-web-bnd.xmi are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<webappbnd:WebAppBinding virtualHostName="default_host" xmi:id="WebAppBinding_1" xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:webappbnd="webappbnd.xmi" xmlns:xmi="omg.org/XMI">
  <webapp href="WEB-INF/web.xml#WebApp_1"></webapp>
  <resRefBindings jndiName="jdbc/Hibernate" xmi:id="ResourceRefBinding_1">
    <bindingResourceRef href="WEB-INF/web.xml#RefHibernate"></bindingResourceRef>
  </resRefBindings> 
  <resRefBindings jndiName="jdbc/Quartz" xmi:id="ResourceRefBinding_2">
    <bindingResourceRef href="WEB-INF/web.xml#RefQuartz"></bindingResourceRef>
  </resRefBindings>
  <resRefBindings jndiName="jdbc/FWHDatasource" xmi:id="ResourceRefBinding_3">
    <bindingResourceRef href="WEB-INF/web.xml#RefFWHDatasource"></bindingResourceRef>
  </resRefBindings>
</webappbnd:WebAppBinding>
```

Comment: To be more precise: I know NPE, but I don't have any idea what might cause it.

Comment: This is an error within the product, and it should not occur, so you should report it to IBM via the PMR process.  That said, the stack trace suggests the issue is related to an ibm-web-bnd.xml or ibm-web-bnd.xmi file.  Do you have either of those files, and can you share their contents?  What version are you running, and have you tried the latest fixpak?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<webappbnd:WebAppBinding virtualHostName="default_host" xmi:id="WebAppBinding_1" xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:webappbnd="webappbnd.xmi" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI">
<webapp href="WEB-INF/web.xml#WebApp_1"></webapp>
<resRefBindings jndiName="jdbc/Hibernate" xmi:id="ResourceRefBinding_1">
<bindingResourceRef href="WEB-INF/web.xml#RefHibernate"></bindingResourceRef>
</resRefBindings>

Comment: <resRefBindings jndiName="jdbc/Quartz" xmi:id="ResourceRefBinding_2">
<bindingResourceRef href="WEB-INF/web.xml#RefQuartz"></bindingResourceRef>
</resRefBindings>
<resRefBindings jndiName="jdbc/FWHDatasource" xmi:id="ResourceRefBinding_3">
<bindingResourceRef href="WEB-INF/web.xml#RefFWHDatasource"></bindingResourceRef>
</resRefBindings>
</webappbnd:WebAppBinding>


I stripped content of the ibm-web-bnd.xmi file over two comments

Comment: I suspect your web.xml is missing a `<resource-ref id="...">` for one of `RefHibernate`, `RefQuartz`, or `RefFWHDatasource`.  Can you show the contents of your web.xml?

Comment: It lacked RefQuartz, since thsi previously was defined in JBOSS' deploy folder. Thanks IMG